# boost beast Websocket Multi Request Server/Client is not really multi

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, websocket, boost-beast

I am writing a c++ project to forward clients websocket requests to server and return their message to each other as soon as each one, this code handles multi clients, but for connecting each client to server async_read stays on the first endpoint, therefore next endpoints however are connected but blocked for reading, by the way every thing is asynchronous.

```
// my server
class websocket_session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<websocket_session>
{
    std::string response = "";

    std::shared_ptr<websocket::stream<beast::tcp_stream>> ws_;

    boost::beast::multi_buffer buffer_;
    boost::beast::multi_buffer buffer_client;

    std::string meth = "", endpoint = "", message = "", host = "", port = "";
    shared_ptr<SocketClient> javaClient;
    net::io_context ioc_client;

public:
    // Take ownership of the socket
    explicit websocket_session(tcp::socket &&socket)
    {
        ws_ = make_shared<websocket::stream<beast::tcp_stream>>(std::move(socket));
    }

    // Start the asynchronous accept operation
    template <class Body, class Allocator>
    void do_accept(http::request<Body, http::basic_fields<Allocator>> req)
    {
        stringstream temprequest;
        temprequest << req.target();
        endpoint = temprequest.str();
        temprequest.str(std::string());
        temprequest << req.method();

        meth = temprequest.str();

        std::cout << "\n\t websocket_session::" << __FUNCTION__ << "\n";

        //Get IP and port in case endpoint is eligible
        if (EndPointSelection::getWebsocketHost(endpoint, meth, req.version(), host, port) == false)
        {
            std::cerr << "\n\t Websocket is NOT Authorized!!\n";
            return;
        }

        // Set suggested timeout settings for the websocket
        ws_->set_option(websocket::stream_base::timeout::suggested(beast::role_type::server));

        // Set a decorator to change the Server of the handshake
        ws_->set_option(websocket::stream_base::decorator(
            [](websocket::response_type &res) {
                res.set(http::field::server,
                        std::string(BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING) +
                            " advanced-server");
            }));

        // Accept the websocket handshake
        ws_->async_accept(req, beast::bind_front_handler(&websocket_session::on_accept, shared_from_this()));
    }

private:
    void on_accept(beast::error_code ec)
    {
        if (ec)
            fail(ec, "accept");

        std::cout << "\n\t websocket_session::" << __FUNCTION__ << "  Endpoint: " << endpoint << "\n";

        javaClient = std::make_shared<SocketClient>(ioc_client);
        javaClient->run(host.c_str(), port.c_str(), endpoint.c_str());
        javaClient->setWebsocket(ws_);

        ioc_client.run();
        do_read();
    }

    void do_read()
    {
        std::cout << "\n\t websocket_session::" << __FUNCTION__ << "\n";
        // Read message from client and keep into our buffer
        ws_->async_read(buffer_, beast::bind_front_handler(&websocket_session::on_read, shared_from_this()));
    }

    void on_read(beast::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);
        std::cout << "\n\t websocket_session::" << __FUNCTION__ << "\n";

        // This indicates that the websocket_session was closed
        if (ec == websocket::error::closed)
            return;

        if (ec)
            fail(ec, "read");

        ws_->text(ws_->got_text());
        if (ws_->got_text())
        {
            std::cout << "\n\t Received Message from Client: " << boost::beast::buffers_to_string(buffer_.data()) << "\n";
            sleep(1); 
        }
        ioc_client.stop();
        //ws_->async_read(buffer_, beast::bind_front_handler(&websocket_session::on_read, shared_from_this()));
    }

    void on_write(beast::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);
        std::cout << "\n\t websocket_session::" << __FUNCTION__ << "\n";
        if (ec)
            fail(ec, "write");

        // Clear the buffer
        buffer_client.consume(buffer_client.size());

        // Do another read
        do_read();
    }
};


//my client
void SocketClient::run(char const *host, char const *port, char const *endpoint)
{
    // Save these for later
    host_ = host;
    endpoint_ = endpoint;
    std::cout << "\n run Endpoint:" << endpoint_ << "\n";

    std::cout << "\nSocketClient::" << __FUNCTION__ << "\n";
    // Look up the domain name
    resolver_.async_resolve(host, port, beast::bind_front_handler(&SocketClient::on_resolve, shared_from_this()));
}

void SocketClient::setWebsocket(std::shared_ptr<websocket::stream<beast::tcp_stream>> ws_cl)
{
    ws_client = ws_cl;
};

void SocketClient::getBuffer(boost::beast::multi_buffer &buffer_client)
{
    buffer_client = buffer_;
}

void SocketClient::writeBuffer(boost::beast::multi_buffer buffer_client)
{
    std::cout << "\nSocketClient::" << __FUNCTION__ << "\n";
    ws_.write(buffer_client.data());
   // ws_.async_write(buffer_client.data(), beast::bind_front_handler(&SocketClient::on_write, shared_from_this()));
    //ws_.async_read(buffer_, beast::bind_front_handler(&SocketClient::on_read, shared_from_this()));
}

void SocketClient::on_resolve(beast::error_code ec, tcp::resolver::results_type results)
{
    if (ec)
        fail(ec, "SocketClient::on_resolve Error: ");
    std::cout << "\nSocketClient::" << __FUNCTION__ << "\n";
    // Set the timeout for the operation

    beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(30));
    // Make the connection on the IP address we get from a lookup
    beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).async_connect(results, beast::bind_front_handler(&SocketClient::on_connect, shared_from_this()));
}

void SocketClient::on_connect(beast::error_code ec, tcp::resolver::results_type::endpoint_type ep)
{
    if (ec)
        fail(ec, "connect");
    std::cout << "\nSocketClient::" << __FUNCTION__ << "\n";
    // Turn off the timeout on the tcp_stream, because
    // the websocket stream has its own timeout system.
    beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).expires_never();

    // Set suggested timeout settings for the websocket
    ws_.set_option(websocket::stream_base::timeout::suggested(beast::role_type::client));

    // Set a decorator to change the User-Agent of the handshake
    ws_.set_option(websocket::stream_base::decorator(
        [](websocket::request_type &req) {
            req.set(http::field::user_agent,
                    std::string(BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING) +
                        " websocket-client-async");
        }));

    // Update the host_ string. This will provide the value of the
    // Host HTTP header during the WebSocket handshake.
    // See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-5.4
    host_ += ':' + std::to_string(ep.port());

    // Perform the websocket handshake
    ws_.async_handshake(host_, endpoint_,
                        beast::bind_front_handler(
                            &SocketClient::on_handshake,
                            shared_from_this()));
}

void SocketClient::on_handshake(beast::error_code ec)
{
    if (ec)
       fail(ec, "SocketClient::on_handshake Error: ");
    std::cout << "\nSocketClient::" << __FUNCTION__ << "\n";
    ws_.async_read(buffer_, beast::bind_front_handler(&SocketClient::on_read, shared_from_this()));
}

void SocketClient::on_write(beast::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);
    buffer_.consume(buffer_.size());
    if (ec)
         fail(ec, "SocketClient::on_write Error: ");
    std::cout << "\nSocketClient::" << __FUNCTION__ << "\n";

    // Read a message from server and keep it into our buffer
    ws_.async_read(buffer_, beast::bind_front_handler(&SocketClient::on_read, shared_from_this()));
}

void SocketClient::do_read()
{
    ws_.async_read(buffer_, beast::bind_front_handler(&SocketClient::on_read, shared_from_this()));
}

void SocketClient::on_read(beast::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);
    std::cout << "\nHi from SocketClient::" << __FUNCTION__ << "\n";
    std::cout << "\nSocketClient::" << __FUNCTION__ << "\n";
    response_.append(boost::beast::buffers_to_string(buffer_.data())) ;

    if (ec)
    {
        fail(ec, "SocketClient::on_read Error: ");
        return;
    }
    if (response_.empty() == false)
    {
        std::cout << "\nServer: " << response_ << "\t Size: " << buffer_.size() << "\n";
        ws_client->write(net::buffer(response_));
        response_="";
    }
    buffer_.consume(buffer_.size());
    sleep(1);
    if (ws_client->got_text())
    {
        std::cout << "\n CLIENT Message\n ";
        ws_.write(buffer_.data());
    }
    ws_.async_read(buffer_, beast::bind_front_handler(&SocketClient::on_read, shared_from_this()));
}

void SocketClient::close_connection()
{
    std::cout << "\nSocketClient::" << __FUNCTION__ << "\n";
    // Close the WebSocket connection
    ws_.async_close(websocket::close_code::normal, beast::bind_front_handler(&SocketClient::on_close, shared_from_this()));
};

void SocketClient::on_close(beast::error_code ec)
{
    if (ec)
        fail(ec, "SocketClient::on_close Error: ");

    std::cout << "\nSocketClient::" << __FUNCTION__ << "\n";
    // If we get here then the connection is closed gracefully
    // The make_printable() function helps print a ConstBufferSequence
    std::cout << beast::make_printable(buffer_.data()) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to understand what your code is doing - as you left some very relevant portions of your code out. And it appears you've got some boiler plate code that is effectively dead code.  The bottom line is this:

I think you need to remove the `ioc_client` from `websocket_session`.  Introducing a layered set of `io_context` instances is going to block subsequent connections and just introduce other issues.

I suspect you are trying to create your own instance of `io_context` because you don't have access to the `io_context` that's in the run state several layers down your call stack.  But I think can get a reference to it.

From the original socket passed into `websocket_session`, invoke `socket.get_executor()` (or is it `socket.get_executor.context()` ?) to get the execution context.  That will enable you to create your socket in SocketClient. Don't invoke `run` on it. It's already in the run state.  If that doesn't work, find a way to get the original `io_context` passed up to your `websocket_session`.